# Expand the clickable area of a html link to the size of the wrapping li element that contains other content

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have basically this html code:

```
<ul class="unordered-list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-block">
      <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google</a>
      <p class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to expand the clickable area of the link to the size of the li element by keeping the links position and the description nicely below the link?

I tried to use absolute positioning for both the link and the description but this fails if for example the link text has a line break. As you can see in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xgcjngvs/3/

I would love to find a solution for this problem without javascript.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that the link tag should only contain the plain text and not any other html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your new requirement there is another way that this can be achieved without changes to your existing HTML structure:

- Remove the `absolute` positioning from `.list-item-link` and `.list-item-link-description`, `position: absolute;` takes the elements out of the document flow and these two need to be aware of how much space each of them take up
- Add a pseudo element to `.list-item-link` using `.list-item-link:after`, make this `position: absolute;` and set the `height` and `width` to take up the dimensions of the container.

```css
.unordered-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.list-item {
    min-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.list-item-link {
    width: 100%;
}
.list-item-link:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.list-item-link-description {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered-list">
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item-block">
            <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google</a>
            <p class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item-block">
            <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google. It is very very very very very very long to demonstrate the linke break.</a>
            <p class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5s44c95q/

Comment: This is what I was trying to get to. Now it doesn't matter what the size of the description or link. Better answer than mine.

Comment: Yes this is really a great solution! You can even vertical center the link as long as you keep the `list-item` the closest `position: relative` element. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your short description will be on 1 line, you can add `padding-bottom` to the `list-item-link` and then move the description up by the same amount and also set a negative `margin-bottom` for the block as a whole. If you do the padding in ems, it should take care of different font sizes.

To make the short description clickable, you need to make the `z-index` of the link higher than the description.

```css
.unordered-list {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:-2em;
    position:relative;
}

.list-item-link {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border:1px #000 solid; /*to show link area */
    padding-bottom:2em;
    z-index:1;
}

.list-item-link-description {
    position:relative;
    top:-2em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered-list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-block">
      <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google</a>
      <p class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-item-block">
      <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google. It is very very very very very very long to demonstrate the linke break.</a>
      <p class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above 2</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This could almost be the solution, but i need the short description clickable without including it in the `list-item-link`. Is that possible?

Comment: OK I managed to get that working using `z-index`. It doesn't work fully with multi-line short descriptions tho

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a few changes to your markup and css:

- Change `list-item-block` into the `a` element and set it as `display: block;`
- Change `list-item-link` and `list-item-link-description` into `span` elements as only `inline` elements are valid in `a` elements
- Style `list-item-link` to look like the link
- Style `list-item-link-description` to look like the paragraph

```css
.unordered-list {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}

.list-item-block {
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.list-item-link {    
  text-decoration: underline;  
}

.list-item-link-description {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered-list">
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-block">
            <span class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google</span>
            <span class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-block">
            <span class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google. It is very very very very very very long to demonstrate the linke break.</span>
            <span class="list-item-link-description">Short description of the link above</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I removed the paragraph tags as you have requested but I can not get it to work any other way without the span, so the span would have to stay in place.

```
<ul class="unordered-list">
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item-block">
            <span class='anchor-control'><a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google</span>
            Short description of the link above
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-item-block">
            <span class='anchor-control'><a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google. It is very very very very very very long to demonstrate the linke break This needs to be a longer link then .</span>
            Short description of the link above
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And here's your CSS.
EDIT: New styles to match the top, it's pretty straight forward stuff

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.anchor-control a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    color: #00f;
}

.unordered-list {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
    position: relative;
    padding; 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.list-item-link {
    position: relative;
}

a .list-item-link-description {
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

EDIT: This should be what you're after.

http://jsfiddle.net/xgcjngvs/9/

Comment: Unfortunately that suffers the same issue

Comment: Ah sorry my screen is rather large so I had to expand the link size once second

Comment: Yes you are correct, but in your fiddle, the second short description still overlaps the link. The issue is to keep the short description positioned underneath the text

Comment: Okay refresh in about a minute, I have a new answer for you

Comment: I threw some more edits up there for you. I am sure this is what you're looking for. it works with line breaks and everything, check out the fiddle for a working demo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i don't want to include more than plain text in the `list-item-link`.

Comment: do you mean just text, no paragraph tags or anything of that sort?

Comment: Yes just text with no paragraphs.

Comment: Okay, I did that up there, the only thing is that there is a span tag on the first line, the span tag needs to be there or this won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```css
css

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.anchor-control{
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.unordered-list {
 padding-left: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
 position: relative;
 padding; 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.list-item-link {
 position: relative;
}

#content {
 display: none;
}
#show:target #content {
 display: inline-block;
}
#show:target #open {
 display: none;
}
.btn-open:after,.btn-close:after{ 
 position:absolute; 
 right:280px;
 top:0;
}
.btn-open:after{
 content: "\25BC";    
}
.btn-close:after{
 content: "\25B2";     
}
```

```html
<ul class="unordered-list">
 <li class="list-item">
 <span class='anchor-control'><a href="www.google.com" class="list-item-link">Sometimes a wrapped link to Google</a></span> 
 <div id="show">
  <a href="#show" id="open" class="btn-open"></a>
  <div id="content">
   Short description of the link above 
  <a href="#hide" id="close" class="btn-close"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

try this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xgcjngvs/13/)**